# Registration and Login form with GWT

Tags: java, gwt

Are there any good tutorials on creating a registration form and login screen with password using Google Web Toolkit?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take a look at the [google-web-toolkit-incubator's Login FAQ](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit-incubator/wiki/LoginSecurityFAQ) which describes how to create a login page and store data in a secure fashion.

Comment: awesome this should help me to do exactly what I need to do. Gracias

Answer (score 4):

if you are using AppEngine, this is probably the best tutorial around.
http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/gettingstarted/usingjsps.html

But even if you arent using the Google AppEngine UserService you can always replace the UserService class with a helper class of your own that can authenticate application users.

Comment: thanks. Not sure if I will be using App Engine just yet though.

Answer (score 2):

[Here is one](http://www.springbyexample.org/examples/simple-gwt-spring-webapp.html)

> Simple GWT Spring Webapp

Comment: The requested URL /examples/simple-gwt-spring-webapp.html was not found on this server.

Answer (score 2):

If you ask the question of "How do I implement a login page for my GWT application?", everyone just redirects you to this semi-complete article: "[LoginSecurity FAQ](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit-incubator/wiki/LoginSecurityFAQ)", which only gives you half the solution. It talks about jBCrypt and the need to communicate sessionID's with every RPC call between the client and the server. However, it does not shed any light on many crucial aspects of the solution:

1) According to the author, checkWithServerIfSessionIdIsStillLegal() method is intended to either display a loginbox if sessionID is no longer legal or allow you access to the main application otherwise. But where do you place this method? Where is "right after your !EntryPoint begins execution"? Is it in a separate GWT application? Is it a different entry point in the same GWT application? Where do you physically call this method from?

2) Immediately relevant to 1 is: where does the loginbox live in this architecture? Again, is it in the same GWT application as the main part you're restricting access to? If so, is it specified as a separate entry point? Or is the LoginBox just a separate GWT Application that is responsible to redirect guests to the main application only if its checkWithServerIfSessionIdIsStillLegal() method returns true?

There are no examples or explanations available, which is quite frustrating.

Comment: yeah man no great solution still thats easy to follow. i have got around this issue by just using gae.

Comment: please don't duplicate [answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10138497/how-to-pass-from-an-entrypoint-to-another-with-gwt). this clutters up the website with redundant content.